# Posting a message box when database records are added, or when an exception is generated

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

sorry if this is a stupid question, but can you help me add some code to my application that generates a MessageBox whenever someone makes a successful addition to the table, and another MessageBox whenever an exception is generated that prevents the desired information from being added to the table? My code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class AddJob : Form
{
    public AddJob()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void AddJob_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\richard.schade\Desktop\IKJobs\WindowsFormsApp1\ikData.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO openJobs (jobTitle, jobDescription, dateOpened, jobsiteLink, jobLocation) VALUES (@jobTitle, @jobDescription, @dateOpened, @jobsiteLink, @jobLocation)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobTitle", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobDescription", textBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOpened", textBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobsiteLink", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobLocation", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your help, I have already learned a lot from this forum.

Comment: In WinForms message boxes are displayed using `MessageBox.Show()`. Use that function and you will find your answer VERY quickly

Comment: Please read ["Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?"](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: Thanks for the input, brand new over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the contents of your method in `try`/`catch`

Do `MessageBox.Show(exception msg)` within catch

And do `MessageBox.Show(successfully done)` as last line of try.

Eg

```
Try{

SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter da;
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\richard.schade\Desktop\IKJobs\WindowsFormsApp1\ikData.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO openJobs (jobTitle, jobDescription, dateOpened, jobsiteLink, jobLocation) VALUES (@jobTitle, @jobDescription, @dateOpened, @jobsiteLink, @jobLocation)", con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobTitle", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobDescription", textBox5.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOpened", textBox4.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobsiteLink", textBox3.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobLocation", textBox2.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("done") ;

} 
Catch(Exception ezx) {

MessageBox.Show("bad");

}
```

Comment: It is `try` and `catch` not `Try` and `Catch` (the first letter is lower case).

Comment: Yes. Lower case. If answer helped, mark it as answer for anyone in future who has same question

Comment: I had to add a few curly brackets, but your solution worked. Thank you both for taking the time!